# Did Kakashi use genjutsu before the end of the Fourth Shinobi War?

Tags: naruto

When you have the Sharingan, you can perform a genjutsu on a person for example, every Uchiha can use this ability. But what about Kakashi? He is not an Uchiha but can he perform genjutsu? If yes, please list it down.

Note: I'm not referring to after the Fourth Shinobi World War, since we know that after the war, Kakashi doesn't have the Sharingan.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you asking if he used genjutsu before he *obtained* the Sharingan, or are you asking if he used genjustu *after* he lost it?  The way that this is worded is a bit confusing to me.

Comment: *After he get the sharingan from obito

Comment: You don’t need a sharingan to use genjustu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you don't need to be an Uchiha to use genjutsu, look at Kurenai she is a genjutsu expert and not an Uchiha. But for your question, Kakashi uses 3 times genjutsu in the series.

1. Against Sakura like @StackUpPhysics said. (During the Bell Test for Team 10 he tricked Sakura by putting her in a Genjutsu.)
2. [Against Zabuza (At 0:33 Minutes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uj5azDnaI_Y).
3. [Against 2 Anbu Ninjas (At 2:41 Minutes)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgT4No6oLp8)

Another Instance of Kakashi Using Genjutsu in the Manga:

[image: Kakashi Using Genjutsu]

Answer (score 3):

I think you want instances of Kakashi using his Genjutsu, here is one-

During the Bell Test for Team 10 he tricked Sakura by putting her in a Genjutsu

Comment: Other than that, is there more?

Comment: @kit there were certainly more I can't seem to recall them and the Wikia doesn't list very many either

Answer (score 1):

**Can Kakashi perform genjutsu?** Yes. According to the [wiki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake),

> With the Sharingan, Kakashi can accurately reproduce any movement he sees (his own physical skill permitting), take in a heightened amount of visual information, and perform the Sharingan's broad category of genjutsu.

Answer (score 1):

Kakashi also uses genjustu during his fight with Obito when he entered the Kamui dimension. Afterward, Kakashi tells Obito enough with the genjustu.

https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kakashi_vs._Obito

And Although not much successful, during the second bell test in ship, Kakashi uses genjustu on Naruto and Sakura at the same time.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgPv3vkrpnY @ 6:10